# react-native-date-picker does not work after update

Tags: android, ios, react-native, mobile, datepicker

I am using `react-native-date-picker:^4.4.0` package. When I've updated my project's react-native version to `0.73.3` from `0.62.7` it stoped working properly. Now, when I tap the field to open picker it gives me an error both on Android and IOS.

```
ERROR  TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'NativeModule.openPicker')
```

In code I use it like that:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, Keyboard } from 'react-native';
import DatePicker from 'react-native-date-picker';
import moment from 'moment';
import i18n from 'app/localize/i18n';
import styles from './styles';

const Input = React.memo(({ mode, label, input, style, minimumDate, maximumDate, ...rest }) => {
  const [date, setDate] = React.useState(new Date());
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  return (
      <DatePicker
        modal
        mode={mode}
        open={open}
        date={date}
        title={null}
        theme='light'
        minimumDate={minimumDate}
        maximumDate={maximumDate}
        onConfirm={handleConfirm}
        onCancel={() => setOpen(false)}
        confirmText={i18n.t('action.confirm')}
        cancelText={i18n.t('action.cancel')}
      />
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
});

export default Input;
```

I know that some methods are missing, but do not pay attention to that, I've removed them on purpose.

Also, I've tried some other date selection packages, but I encounter errors with them also, like `@react-native-community/datetimepicker:7.6.2` gives an error

```
'requireNativeComponent: "RNDatePicker" was not found in the UIManager.'
```

Comment: You must need to re-run your app after this package installation.

Comment: @PawanKumarKushwaha I already did it, but it still does not work. Any tips how to do it properly?